# ModernDialog.ShowMessage Error: "Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has not been shown previously."

Tags: wpf

I am having an issue, same as _benji here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053087/cannot-set-owner-property-to-a-window-that-has-not-been-shown-previously, whereby I cannot get the ModernDialog to show the message, has anyone had and solved this issue before?

```
System.Windows.MessageBoxResult response = ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Cannot connect; try again?", "Connection Status", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error suggest the place you are calling the code from, has not yet shown any window to the user. You need to first show a window to the user before trying to show it, or make sure you show the dialog before closing the last window.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Michal, I was having a bit of a 'lapse' in thought :)   The window was closing before the dialog opened.